# How to eliminate reverse data from my table

Tags: sql

I'm super new to SQL and trying to learn it. I have a table such as ( name_1, name_2, room) 
There are lots of duplicate in my table that I'm trying to eliminate
( name_1, name_2, room) & ( name_2, name_1, room) is a duplicate for me

I have something like this

```
John         Robert       C21
Mary         Joe          C22
Joe          Mary         C22
```

how can i turn it to

```
John         Robert       C21
Mary         Joe          C22
```

Comment: What database are you using?  And version?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to insert a serial, a unique identifier (id) to make it work, and modified the query:

```
DELETE FROM tabl                                                 
WHERE id = (
  SELECT t1.id FROM tabl t1, tabl t2 WHERE t1.name_1 = t2.name_2
  AND t1.name_2 = t2.name_1
  AND t1.room = t2.room
  AND t1.name_1 > t2.name_1);
```

Define for yourself, how you like to order the columns. I would simply order name(1,2) alphabetically in future.

So after removing the duplicates, I would update all rows where name_2 < name_1 to prevent duplicates in future.

Maybe a different table structure would be more appropriate? Are there always two names?

If you just have tbl:=(name, room), you could have

```
John   C21
Robert C21
Mary   C22
Joe    C22
```

The problem wouldn't happen.

Comment: thanks for you time Mark, I did the same but keep getting error                      FROM  PublicationListNoDup t1, PublicationListNoDup t2

Comment: @user996554 - You need to tell us what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @user996554: a) I'm not Mark. b) I guess the 'solution' doesn't work, and we need a unique index for each row here - at least it would make things more easy.